# Replace character in array list python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a python list like the following.

```
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

how to convert it to this format??

```
{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

Comment: This is a `set` of `set`s, you can't have this.

Comment: Set is an unhashable type so you can't have a set of sets as @Guy said. Even {0, 0} or {1, 1} is not possible (sets eliminates duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following:

```
start = [(0, 0), (1, 1)]
result = set()

for element in start:
   result.add(element)

print(result)
```

As everyone said, you can't have `{1,1}` or `{0,0}` since sets can't have repeated elements, But you can have the tuples as elements (the code I gave).